# Add css link in sub folder, php extension file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am new and trying to add CSS in DOCTOR folder **add.php** from directors.

Here is the folder directory:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        header('location: login.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>

     Responsive Bootstrap Advance Admin Template
    </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php include 'images/mem2.png';?>" />
    <!-- BOOTSTRAP STYLES-->
    <link href="../assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- FONTAWESOME STYLES-->
    <link href="../assets/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!--CUSTOM BASIC STYLES-->
    <link href="../assets/css/basic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!--CUSTOM MAIN STYLES-->
    <link href="../assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- GOOGLE FONTS-->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

This is how I link external css in to my page, but result is not satisfactory. The output is below:

output:

[image]

No css is added.

Comment: It's usually better to use absolute paths from the root as opposed to relative paths from your current file. You should `link` your stylesheets from `/assets/css/...` instead

Comment: i have tried that but still not working, could  you give me an example please

Answer (score 0):

Don't use include() inside an href and make sure you close that head tag

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo 'images/mem2.png';?>" />
```

Or just

```
<?php include 'images/mem2.png';?>
```

Comment: thank you for quick replay, I did as you mention but result is still same and please tell me how could i add css it also not working

Comment: Then I think you have the wrong URLs. Replace the hrefs will the full URL https://...com/...css